# llvm 3.42 build from source fails on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, llvm

I have a script that builds llvm/clang 3.42 from source
(with configure+make).
**It runs smooth on ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS**.
When I upgraded to **ubuntu 17.04**, the build fails.

Here is the building script:

```
svn co https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/RELEASE_342/final llvm
svn co https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/tags/RELEASE_342/final llvm/tools/clang
svn co https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/tags/RELEASE_342/final llvm/projects/compiler-rt
svn co https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/tags/RELEASE_342/final llvm/projects/libcxx

rm -rf llvm/.svn
rm -rf llvm/tools/clang/.svn
rm -rf llvm/projects/compiler-rt/.svn
rm -rf llvm/projects/libcxx/.svn

cd llvm
./configure \
--enable-optimized \
--disable-assertions \
--enable-targets=host \
--with-python="/usr/bin/python2"

make -j `nproc`
```

Here are the errors I get (TLDR: problems with definitions of **malloc**, **calloc**, **realloc** and **free**)

```
/usr/include/malloc.h:38:14: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
             ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:427:14: note: target of using declaration
extern void *malloc (size_t __size) __THROW __attribute_malloc__ __wur;
             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3./stdlib.h:65:12: note: using declaration
using std::malloc;
           ^
In file included from /home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_platform_linux.cc:47:
/usr/include/malloc.h:41:14: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in
  scope
extern void *calloc (size_t __nmemb, size_t __size)
             ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:429:14: note: target of using declaration
extern void *calloc (size_t __nmemb, size_t __size)
             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/stdlib.h:59:12: note: using declaration
using std::calloc;
           ^
In file included from /home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_platform_linux.cc:47:
/usr/include/malloc.h:49:14: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in
  scope
extern void *realloc (void *__ptr, size_t __size)
             ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:441:14: note: target of using declaration
extern void *realloc (void *__ptr, size_t __size)
             ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/stdlib.h:73:12: note: using declaration
using std::realloc;
           ^
In file included from /home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_platform_linux.cc:47:
/usr/include/malloc.h:53:13: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in
  scope
extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
            ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:444:13: note: target of using declaration
extern void free (void *__ptr) __THROW;
            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/stdlib.h:61:12: note: using declaration
using std::free;
           ^
COMPILE:   clang_linux/tsan-x86_64/x86_64: /home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_rtl_mutex.cc
4 errors generated.
Makefile:267: recipe for target '/home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/tsan-x86_64/x86_64/SubDir.lib__tsan__rtl/tsan_platform_linux.o' failed
make[5]: *** [/home/oren/GIT/LatestKlee/llvm/tools/clang/runtime/compiler-rt/clang_linux/tsan-x86_64/x86_64/SubDir.lib__tsan__rtl/tsan_platform_linux.o] Error 1
```

The default gcc version shipped with ubuntu 17.04 is 6.3.
Maybe this is an issue of default C++ dialect used by gcc 6.3?
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be an issue with LLVM 3.4.2`tsan` (Thread Sanitizer) failing to build with GCC 6.x, as previously reported here:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/clang34-analyzer-split

It seems the inclusion of `stdlib.h` and `malloc.h` is conflicting, since both define `malloc` and friends.

It's possible that this issue only manifets in `tsan`, so if `tsan` is not instrumental to your LLVM build (which is very likely), and you wish to stick with the system gcc for building LLVM, you may consider disabling `tsan` completely.

If you're running a CMake build (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188796/clang-4-0-fails-to-build-clang-3-42-on-ubuntu-17-04/48226872#48226872)), you can do so by commenting line 29 of `llvm/projects/compiler-rt/lib/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME MATCHES "Linux" AND NOT ANDROID)  
  add_subdirectory(tsan) # comment out this line
```

If you're forced to stick to the `configure` build, my best guess would be removing the `tsan-x86_64` target in `llvm/projects/compiler-rt/make/clang_linux.mk`, line 63:

```
Configs += full-x86_64 profile-x86_64 san-x86_64 asan-x86_64 --> tsan-x86_64 <--
```

Comment: many thanks for all the effort, I indeed do not need tsan, and when disabling everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on my Ubuntu 16.10.
It has default gcc 6.2. You need to instruct LLVM build system to use gcc 4.9. Also, I suggest you remove GCC6 completely.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove g++-6 gcc-6 cpp
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++4.9
$ export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.9
$ export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.9
$ export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp-4.9
$ ./configure
$ make
```

And maybe you will need:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/cpp-4.9 /usr/bin/cpp
```

Comment: Note that there's probably no need to remove the installed gcc - different versions could happily live together. You could toggle between them using `update-alternatives --config gcc` or just specify the version number as you suggest, such as `gcc-4.9`. Generally removing system gcc is not advisable.

Comment: Also, it's important to install multilib as well:
`sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++4.9 g++-4.9-multilib`
Or you may end up with a partial and broken gcc installtion.

Comment: Thanks Alexander and @valiano, but it seems I can't even install gcc-4.9 on Ubuntu 17.04 for some reason ... I have posted that separately in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398475/fail-to-install-gcc-4-9-in-ubuntu17-04 ...